# How to swap values between before and after `=` using SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, swap

I have declared and set a value in parameter `@Data` as `ACCOUNT_NO|none|M=ACCOUNT_NO,ADD1|none|M=ADD1`

I need to get a result as `ACCOUNT_NO=ACCOUNT_NO|none|M,ADD1=ADD1|none|M`.

Which means I need to swap between the values before and after `=`

```
Declare @Data varchar(100);

Set @Data ='ACCOUNT_NO|none|M=ACCOUNT_NO,ADD1|none|M=ADD1'

select @Data
```

How to swap the values between before and after `=` using SQL Server?

Expected Output if I execute the query `ACCOUNT_NO=ACCOUNT_NO|none|M,ADD1=ADD1|none|M`. Can anyone give an idea to do this one?

Comment: I reflected this within my answer with: This is a string which could contain multiple parts, separated with a comma. Each part contains a "=" and should be swapped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Declare @Data varchar(100)='ACCOUNT_NO|none|M=ACCOUNT_NO,ADD1|none|M=ADD1';

WITH
myCTE1 AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<root><r>' + REPLACE(@Data,',','</r><r>') + '</r></root>' AS XML) AS parts1
)
,myCTE2 AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<root><r>' + REPLACE(p1.x.value('.','varchar(max)'),'=','</r><r>') + '</r></root>' AS XML) as parts2 
    FROM myCTE1
    CROSS APPLY parts1.nodes('/root/r') AS p1(x)
)
SELECT STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT ',' + parts2.value('/root[1]/r[2]','varchar(max)') + '=' + parts2.value('/root[1]/r[1]','varchar(max)')
        FROM myCTE2
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
    ).value('.','varchar(max)'),1,1,'');

/* Result
ACCOUNT_NO=ACCOUNT_NO|none|M,ADD1=ADD1|none|M
*/
```

Comment: Excellent Answer! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Pleased to help you :-)

Comment: Is it possible to do the same thing in Oracle? Is yes I will ask that as a new question in SO.

Comment: Sorry, don't know... Anyway the approach is: split it by ",", the split it by "=" and the re-concatenate it. This will work somehow...

Comment: Ok Thanks dear for your help :)