# How to swap values between before and after `=` using Oracle?

Tags: oracle, swap

I have declared a value in parameter `@Data` as `ACCOUNT_NO|none|M=ACCOUNT_NO,ADD1|none|M=ADD1`

I need to get a result as `ACCOUNT_NO=ACCOUNT_NO|none|M,ADD1=ADD1|none|M`.

Which means I need to swap between the values before and after `=`

I have the [SQL Server Query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32139238/4849534) for achieving this but I need Oracle query.

```
Declare @Data varchar(100)='ACCOUNT_NO|none|M=ACCOUNT_NO,ADD1|none|M=ADD1';

WITH
myCTE1 AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<root><r>' + REPLACE(@Data,',','</r><r>') + '</r></root>' AS XML) AS parts1
)
,myCTE2 AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<root><r>' + REPLACE(p1.x.value('.','varchar(max)'),'=','</r><r>') + '</r></root>' AS XML) as parts2 
    FROM myCTE1
    CROSS APPLY parts1.nodes('/root/r') AS p1(x)
)
SELECT STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT ',' + parts2.value('/root[1]/r[2]','varchar(max)') + '=' + parts2.value('/root[1]/r[1]','varchar(max)')
        FROM myCTE2
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
    ).value('.','varchar(max)'),1,1,'');
```

Expected Output if I execute the query `ACCOUNT_NO=ACCOUNT_NO|none|M,ADD1=ADD1|none|M`. Can anyone give an idea to do this one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a job for REGEXP_REPLACE:

```
WITH datatab as (select 'ACCOUNT_NO|none|M=ACCOUNT_NO,ADD1|none|M=ADD1' info from dual)
select info,
       regexp_replace(info, '([^=]+)=([^=,]+),([^=]+)=([^=,]+)', '\2=\1,\4=\3') new_info
from   datatab;

INFO                                          NEW_INFO                                     
--------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------
ACCOUNT_NO|none|M=ACCOUNT_NO,ADD1|none|M=ADD1 ACCOUNT_NO=ACCOUNT_NO|none|M,ADD1=ADD1|none|M
```

(as a complete aside, that's the first time I've ever written a regular expression and had it work first time. Apparently, I have gone over to the dark side... *{;-) )

ETA: If you need this in a procedure/function, you don't need to bother selecting the regular expression, you can do it in PL/SQL directly.

Here's an example of a function that returns the swapped over result:

```
create or replace function swap_places (p_data in varchar2)
return varchar2
is
begin
  return regexp_replace(p_data, '([^=]+)=([^=,]+),([^=]+)=([^=,]+)', '\2=\1,\4=\3');
end swap_places;
/

-- example of calling the function to check the result
select swap_places('ACCOUNT_NO|none|M=ACCOUNT_NO,ADD1|none|M=ADD1') col1 from dual;

COL1
-------------------------------------------------
ACCOUNT_NO=ACCOUNT_NO|none|M,ADD1=ADD1|none|M
```

Comment: Superb Answer! Thanks for your help :)